# Запрет подключения пользователю на сервер при неверном пароле Linux

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, password

Настроил свой удаленный сервер на Centos 7 так чтобы при неверном пароле запрещалось подключение пользователю на определенное время, так как делал это давно то уже ничего не помню как там и что, и вот ввел неверный пароль и сейчас сам как root не могу зайти на него через WinSCP, однако через ssh провайдера доступ есть, помогите что надо ввести чтобы разрешить доступ для пользователя с именем root.

Comment: Зайти другим пользователем (если есть) и из него зайти в `root` : `su -`. Если вспомнили пароль. Как разрешить руту зайти через `ssh` найдёте.

Comment: Где и что вы настроили? Сам `sshd` или похожую на `failtoban` утилиту? Пересмотрите парольный рутовый доступ по ssh на полный запрет рутового входа и авторизацию по ключам.